# Dynamic pricing calculator in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

****Edited***

I'm building a dynamic pricing calculator feature using vue js. I've made the  code and there are still some problems that make the features that I made not work properly. I have a dropdown menu which when clicked will display different tabs and different content (dynamic component). And also I have an estimate card for details and prices, and every item can be deleted.

I have several problems which are as follows:

[image]

1. When I was on the `Storage` tab, and submit data after I selected several options, the software tab details and price also appeared in estimation card. I want is the pricing details just the `Storage`. Likewise if I just submit in the `Software` tab, then only details and prices appear from the `Software` tab. And if I submit in `Software` and `Storage`, the result of both will appear.
2. When I submit data on the `Storage` tab, and I go to the `Software` tab, the price details on the estimation card are gone. I want the data still appear. it's not possible if I use `<keep-alive>` because it's not a dynamic component.
3. I have the delete button item in the estimation card. What I want it to be will delete the item according to the option that was clicked. But still not working very well.

Currently, I only have 2 tabs, Storage and Software. If I have other tabs, how do I make this system dynamic?

Can anyone help me solve this problem and explain it step by step?

this is my code that I made on Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-price-calculator-o77ig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must make the priceEstimationData dynamic. You can show the data from props without using watch. I'm only providing some code here. For full version please go to the codesandbox.

```html
<!-- PriceEstimation.vue -->

<template v-if="priceEstimationData">
    <div
      :key="id"
      v-for="(data, id) in priceEstimationData"
      class="estimation-category"
    >
      <div class="category-price d-flex justify-content-between">
      {{ data ? data.type[0].toUpperCase() + data.type.slice(1) : ""}}
        <a href="#" @click="removeItem(id)">Delete</a>
      </div>
      <table class="table table-borderless">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>
                Storage Type: <span>{{ data.typeName }}</span>
              </p>
              <p>
                Quantity Storage: <span>{{ data.qunantity }}</span>
              </p>
              <p>
                Duration Storage: <span>{{ data.duration }}</span>
              </p>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <p>${{ data.typeValue }}</p>
              <p>${{ data.qunantity * data.quantityPrice }}</p>
              <p>${{ data.duration * data.durationPrice }}</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </template>
```

2. After looking at your code. I notice that you are using the watch property. I have removed the watch property to make the estimation data still. See the code below

```js
// TheCalculator.vue

// remove watch that makes the priceEstimationData null
/* watch: {
 selectedTab: function () {
   this.priceEstimationData = null;
 },
}, */
computed: {
 selectedTabProps() {
   return this.selectedTab === "storage-calculator"
     ? { event: this.setPriceEstimationData }
     : null;
 },
},
```

3. I have modified your code and move the removeItem methods to parent. Because the child only read the data. See below

```js
// TheCalculator.vue

methods: {
 setSelectedTab(tab) {
  this.selectedTab = tab;
 },
 setPriceEstimationData(data) {
  this.priceEstimationData.push(data);
 },
 removeItem(id) {
  // remove findIndex function
  this.priceEstimationData.splice(id, 1);
 },
},
```

I have modified `TheCalculator.vue`, `PriceEstimation.vue`, `ServiceCalculator.vue`, and `StorageCalculator.vue`.

**Edit**

I have fixed the duration bug in ServiceCalculator.vue

```js
// ServiceCalculator.vue

// fixes duration bug
updateDurationServices(val) {
 this.duration = val;
},
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-price-calculator-forked-ls7n6

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very crude bunch of components that gets this job done - without the `SUBMIT` button.

```js
Vue.component("ProductSetup", {
  props: ['productKey', 'product'],
  methods: {
    handleInputChange(e) {
      this.$emit("update:product-type", {
        ...e,
        product: this.productKey,
      })
    },
    handleQuantityChange(e) {
      this.$emit("update:product-quantity", {
        ...e,
        product: this.productKey,
      })
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <label
        v-for="(val, key) in product.types"
        :key="key"
      >
        {{ key }}
        <input
          type="radio"
          :value="val"
          :name="productKey"
          @change="() => handleInputChange({ type: key })"
        />
      </label>
      <input
        type="number"
        min="0"
        @input="(e) => handleQuantityChange({ quantity: e.target.value })"
      />
    </div>
  `,
})

Vue.component("PriceEstimate", {
  props: ["products"],
  template: `
    <div>
      <div
        v-for="(product, productKey) in products"
      >
        {{ productKey }}<br />
        {{ productKey }} {{ product.chosen }}: {{ product.types[product.chosen] }}<br />
        Quantity {{ productKey }}: {{ product.quantity * product.pricePerPiece }}<br />
        TOTAL: {{ product.types[product.chosen] + product.quantity * product.pricePerPiece }}
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    estimates() {
      return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(
          this.products
        ).filter(([key, val]) => {
          return val.chosen && val.quantity
        })
      )
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      products: {
        storage: {
          chosen: null,
          types: {
            type1: 60,
            type2: 70,
          },
          pricePerPiece: 20,
          quantity: null,
        },
        os: {
          chosen: null,
          types: {
            os1: 60,
            os2: 70,
            os3: 80,
          },
          pricePerPiece: 35,
          quantity: null,
        },
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleUpdateProduct({
      type,
      product
    }) {
      this.products[product]["chosen"] = type
    },
    handleUpdateQuantity({
      quantity,
      product
    }) {
      this.products[product]["quantity"] = quantity
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <div
        v-for="(obj, product) in products"
      >
        Chosen {{ product }}: {{ obj.chosen }}<br />
        Quantity of {{ product }}: {{ obj.quantity }}
        <hr />
        <product-setup
          :product-key="product"
          :product="obj"
          @update:product-type="(e) => handleUpdateProduct(e)"
          @update:product-quantity="(e) => handleUpdateQuantity(e)"
        />
        <hr />
      </div>
      <price-estimate
        :products="estimates"
      />
    </div>
  `,
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the parameter received by priceEstimationData, it does have servicesDuration nor servicesTypePrice.

In ServiceCalculator.vue, the "data" is:

```
var data = {
    servicesTypeName: selectedServicesType.name,
    servicesTypeValue: selectedServicesType.value,
    qunantity: this.quantiti,
    durationServices: this.durationServices,
};
```

You must pass also the propierties servicesDuration  and servicesTypePrice.

Regards

Comment: i adding ```servicesTypePrice: this.servicesTypePrice, serviceDuration: this.servicesDuration``` still not working

Comment: What I see is that there is no consistency when setting propierty priceEstimationData.

When calling "setPriceEstimationData" you must pass all the propierties.

As a quick fix, you can do this in "PriceEstimation.vue": 

 watch: {
    priceEstimationData: function (data) {
...
        this.servicesType = data.servicesTypeName;
        this.servicesTypePrice = data.servicesTypeValue ? data.servicesTypeValue : 0;
        this.servicesQuantity = data.qunantity;
        this.servicesDuration = data.durationServices ? data.durationServices : 0;
...  
  },
    
Regards